# Asking for a list in input?

Tags: python

Is there a way to add all the input numbers to a list?

I mean like this:

```
 input = ("Type in a list of numbers") e.g [2,-3,5,6,-1]
```

and then make all those numbers into a list?

I thought maybe like this but it doesn't work,

```
input = ("Type in a list of numbers")
ls = []

ls.append(input)
```

Comment: Can you give example input? Are they separated by spaces, or commas, does it begin and end with `[`, `]`, e.g. `1 2 3`, or `1, 2, 3`, or `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: What version of python are you using? 2.7 will try to convert the input to a type.

Comment: @PeterWood There is no `input()` in the OP's code ;)

Comment: Do you _really_ want the user to have to type the brackets and commas? It'd be simpler for them to just enter `2 -3 5 6 -1`, and it's simple to code, too.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.7 will just work:

```
>>> input() # [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]

>>> type(_)
list
```

Python 3:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(input()) # [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can input a list of numbers like this in Python 2:

```
list_of_numbers = [input('Number 1:'), input('Number 2:'), input('Number 3:')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse a list of numbers entered by the user:

```
import ast

numbers = input('Type in a list of numbers, separated by comma:\n')

lst = list(ast.literal_eval(numbers)))

print('You entered the following list of numbers:')
print(lst)
```

```
Type in a list of numbers, separated by comma:
1, 523, 235235, 34645, 56756, 21124, 346346, 658568, 123123, 345, 2
You entered the following list of numbers:
[1, 523, 235235, 34645, 56756, 21124, 346346, 658568, 123123, 345, 2]
```

Note that with Python 2, you need to use `raw_input()` instead of just `input()`.

Comment: This works because the comma separated values are evaluated to be a tuple, which `list` then converts to a list.